# What is DIP (dual inline package)?

Tags: computer-architecture, assembly, motherboard

I searched on the net, but couldn't understand what DIP is. Is it RAM?

Comment: You can buy milk or juice in a bottle and you can buy them in a carton. To put it simple, DIP is a bottle for semiconductor drinks

Comment: This is such a basic question that I find it hard to believe that you really did any research on your own. Do you have a more specific question? What have you learned so far?

Answer (score 3):

[It is a package type consisting of two rows of inline pins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_in-line_package)

Answer (score 1):

DIP is a package. It just means that the device is in a package with two parallel lines of pins.

Many hundreds of thousands of different types of ICs, DC-DC converters, Relays, and so on come in DIP packages.